# How to fix improperly uninstalled software on Raspberry Pi (Buster)

Tags: software-installation, raspberry-pi, out-of-memory, intellij

First and foremost, I'm trying to purge an improperly **uninstalled** version of Intellij-Idea on Raspberry Pi and reinstall.

I installed IntelliJ-Idea on the Raspberry Pi using the below page as a guide:

[Install Intellij-Idea on Raspberry Pi](https://pavelfatin.com/install-intellij-idea-on-raspberry-pi/)

After progressive success decreasing CPU/memory usage, and countless lock-up and kill the jvm loops, I ran into a wall with continuing "OutOfMemory" exceptions after the application launched fine and ran for a few minutes.  (It indexes nearly the entire JVM, maven, my home folder, etc.)

Yes, I increased JVM memory allocation (-Xms/-Xmx), increased swap space, etc.  Thinking the root of my problem might be a caching issue, I tried to remove a few folders I thought were cache directories, but actually wiped out the main install image and all subdirectories instead.

So now I'm trying to force uninstall/delete so I can re-install.
I've tried:

1. Uninstalling from Add/Remove Software (Only supporting packages list as "installed".  The main install doesn't list at all)
2. sudo apt-get purge/remove intelliJ* (see below output)
3. sudo apt purge/remove intelliJ* (ditto)
4. Got frustrated and manually deleted all the other "IdeaIC2021.2" and related folders (after backing up key config files)  The start menu link won't work now of course, but I can't get pi to truly purge details and let me reinstall.

Bizarre half-installed state messages:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt purge intelliJ*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libjdom2-intellij-java-doc' for regex 'intelliJ*'
Note, selecting 'libintellij-annotations-java-doc' for regex 'intelliJ*'
Note, selecting 'libjdom2-intellij-java' for regex 'intelliJ*'
Note, selecting 'libintellij-annotations-java' for regex 'intelliJ*'
Package 'libintellij-annotations-java' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libintellij-annotations-java-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libjdom2-intellij-java' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libjdom2-intellij-java-doc' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Yes, I'm an idiot for deleting the wrong folder and then digging the hole deeper, but at this point I just want to overlay with a new install anyway.  What's the correct way forward?  Manual download and install because pi's registration details are horked?  A set of sudo apt-get install commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually downloaded a new installation since the Add/Remove software option wasn't letting me go further.  It wasn't perfect, but it was better than a dead-end.  In my search, I stumbled across this:

[JetBrains ends 32-bit OS support](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/04/end-of-support-for-32-bit-operating-systems-in-intellij-based-ides/)

JetBrains only supported 32bit up to 2021.1.x, and the current version is 2021.3.x.  I downloaded a down-level version here:

[Install other/mostly older versions of Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html)

Otherwise I need to wait until Raspbian officially supports 64-bit:

[Raspberry Pi 64 bit status](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-64-bit/)